# When should I use System.IO.Stream (or derived class) vs a simple Byte[]?

Tags: c#, security, architecture, stream

I'm porting over some C++ and Java code to C# and see all the data IO as Streams, when all the streams are less than 1K in size.

Given that the buffer size of the stream equals the whole stream in almost all circumstances, is there any reason I shouldn't simply use a Byte[]?

The 1K data units are arriving *from* a stream source (network or disk) however, once read into memory, the stream access is a little random.  I think direct byte[x] access might be more efficient (or logical).

So my question, is it generally acceptable from a security and architecture perspective to use Byte[] array directly instead of wrapping it in a stream?  Assume that no further "stream" access is needed for other operations (e.g. an encoded media stream).

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that the usage is "a little random," I think a byte array makes the most sense; these are inherently good for lookup at a given position, while a stream would require you to do a linear read and reset the position.  I'm not sure what security concerns you might have, but if you're passing the array to any unmanaged resources you might want to consider pinning it in memory.